# What's happening to values in list?

Tags: python

For self-practice, I'm writing a dictionary program that stores data in the following data structure: `[(average,month),(average,month),....,(average,month)]`. The datafile is called table.csv and can be found in the link:

http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/PracticeOfComputingUsingPython/05_ListsTuples/AppleStock/

The question I have is why does the list, `testList[x][0]`, go blank when this condition becomes false?:

```
if dates == UniqueDates[x]:
```

When `x = 0`, such that `testList[0][0]`, and the condition is `True`, the list is `[474.98, 468.22, 454.7, 455.19, 439.76, 450.99]`. But, when it becomes `False`, that same list, `testList[0][0]`, mysteriously becomes `[ ]`. Why aren't the values in the list being kept?

```
f = open('table.csv','r').readlines()
col = 6

testList = []
uniqueDates = []

x = 0
for i in range(1,len(f)):
    dates = f[i].split(',')[0][:7]
    column = float(f[i].split(',')[col])
    if dates not in uniqueDates:
        uniqueDates.append(dates)
        testList.append(())
        testList[x] = [],dates
    if dates == uniqueDates[x]:
        testList[x][0].append(column)
    else:
        testList[x][0].append((mean(testList[x][0]),uniqueDates[x]))
        x += 1
        testList[x][0].append(column)
```

Comment: What is `mean`? in `testList[x][0].append((mean(testList[x][0]),uniqueDates[x]))` ?

Comment: The mean comes from the module called statistics I imported.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this section:

```
if dates not in uniqueDates:
    uniqueDates.append(dates)
    testList.append(())
    testList[x] = [],dates
```

The first time this executes is when processing line 7, the first time the month changes.  Before executing this section, `x == 0`; so the last line in this block replaces the first element of `testList`.  I think you want it to replace the new empty element that you just appended.

I suspect what you want here is to simply combine the last two lines into one:

```
if dates not in uniqueDates:
    uniqueDates.append(dates)
    testList.append(([],dates))
```